# Cannot see terminal input after quitting python interpreter

Tags: python, macos, terminal, interpreter

I recently updated to OSX 11 and re-installed python using MacPorts. However, now whenever I enter the basic python interpreter from the terminal then quit, everything I type in the terminal in invisible. It still works - I can enter commands and run them - but I cannot see what I'm typing.

Some behavior I have found:

1) This error is fixed if I reset the input using the command 'stty echo' (until I run the interpreter again)

2) This does not happen for any programs other than python (e.g., my R interpreter works just fine)

3) It seems to be limited to the interpreter since I can still see terminal input after running a python script (or running: python -c "print 'hello'")

4) This happens identically for the interpreter for python27 and python35

I assume this is an issue with directing stdin, but I'm not sure what might be causing this or how to fix it. It's more annoying than disastrous, but I was hoping someone might have some clue of how to correct this.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you quitting the interpreter? I have this same issue happen if I use the Tkinter module in Python, then quit the application, but I don't have the issue if I quit the interpreter with `exit()`. Interesting that you found a way to fix the issue - I wasn't aware of it. Anyways, this is probably a bug in the Python interpreter - you should report it on bugs.python.org.

Comment: I am quitting with either exit() or quit(), and this is without using Tkinter (even entering python then immediately exiting causes this error). And I will report the bug. Thanks!

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I'd be hesitant to report a bug without more research.

Comment: You could look through `sys.modules`, especially site-specific stuff, to see if any exotic packages installed. perhaps there is an output colorizor or readline module that fiddles with your terminal output for prettying up the display.